# Recursive regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling with a regex expression. Here is the text I'm working on:

```
* [[February 1]] – ''[[Brave New World]]'', a novel by [[Aldous Huxley]], is first published.
* [[February 2]]
** A general [[World Disarmament Conference]] begins in [[Geneva]]. The principal issue at the conference is the demand made by Germany for ''gleichberechtigung'' ("equality of status" i.e. abolishing Part V of the Treaty of Versailles, which had disarmed Germany) and the French demand for ''sécurité'' ("security" i.e. maintaining Part V).
** The [[League of Nations]] again recommends negotiations between the [[Republic of China (1912–49)|Republic of China]] and Japan.
** The [[Reconstruction Finance Corporation]] begins operations in Washington, D.C.
* [[February 4]]
** The [[1932 Winter Olympics]] open in [[Lake Placid, New York]].
** Japan occupies [[Harbin]], China.
* [[February 9]] – [[Junnosuke Inoue]], prominent Japanese businessman, banker and former governor of the Bank of Japan is assassinated by right-wing extremist group the League of Blood in the [[League of Blood Incident]].
* [[February 11]] – [[Pope Pius XI]] meets [[Benito Mussolini]] in [[Vatican City]].
```

I would like to have a regex to match all lines which begin with an `*` which is followed by any number of lines beginning with `**`. Ideally, I would like to have each lines with `**` in a group.

Here is the result I'd like to have:

```
> Match 1:
>> Group 1: "* [[February 2]]"

>> Group 2: "** A general [...] Part V)."

>> Group 3: "** The [[League of Nations]] [...] and Japan."

>> Group 4: "** The [[Reconstruction Finance Corporation]] begins operations in Washington, D.C."

> Match 2: 
>> Group 1: "* [[February 4]]"

>> Group 2: "** The [[1932 Winter Olympics]] open in [[Lake Placid, New York]]."

>> Group 3: "** Japan occupies [[Harbin]], China."
```

(I've put [...] for shortening purpose.)

Here is
I come to this pattern: `/(*ANY)^\*{1} (.*)\n(?>(^\*{2}(.*?)\n)+)/gm`, here is a link to regex101 where I test my regex: https://regex101.com/r/ubtnMg/1.

Here is a description of my pattern:
* `(*ANY)` to match any newline sequences because I'm not sure which newline character they use in text.
* `^\*{1} (.*)\n` to match any line which begin with `*`, capture the text of the line until there is a newline.
* `(?>(^\*{2}(.*?)\n)+)` is the tricky part. It's supposed to match every line after `^\*{1} (.*)\n` which begin with `**`, capture the text until the end of line in a group, and until it find a new line which begin with `*`

It actually give me this:

```
> Match 1: "* [[February 2]]
** A general [[World Disarmament Conference]] begins in [[Geneva]]. The principal issue at the conference is the demand made by Germany for ''gleichberechtigung'' ("equality of status" i.e. abolishing Part V of the Treaty of Versailles, which had disarmed Germany) and the French demand for ''sécurité'' ("security" i.e. maintaining Part V).
** The [[League of Nations]] again recommends negotiations between the [[Republic of China (1912–49)|Republic of China]] and Japan.
** The [[Reconstruction Finance Corporation]] begins operations in Washington, D.C."
>> Group 1: "[[February 2]]"

>> Group 2: "** The [[Reconstruction Finance Corporation]] begins operations in Washington, D.C."

>> Group 3: "The [[Reconstruction Finance Corporation]] begins operations in Washington, D.C."

> Match 2: "* [[February 4]]
** The [[1932 Winter Olympics]] open in [[Lake Placid, New York]].
** Japan occupies [[Harbin]], China."
>> Group 1: "[[February 4]]"

>> Group 2: "** Japan occupies [[Harbin]], China"

>> Group 3: " Japan occupies [[Harbin]], China."
```

I hope I've been clear enough and you can help me with this. Don't hesitate to ask for more details.

Comment: You can't capture each line in a separate group. Regex can't dynamically spawn capture groups. So what you want isn't possible. Also, I don't see a recursive regex anywhere.

Comment: So I have to capture the all group, and then do another regex to match every line ?

Comment: That is one possible solution, yes. You can also do it without regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Rawing, I've come across this solution:

First, I use this pattern: `/(*ANY)^\*{1} (.*)\n(^\*{2}(.*?)\n)+/gm` to match every block of text like this:

```
* [[February 2]]
** A general [[World Disarmament Conference]] begins in [[Geneva]]. The principal issue at the conference is the demand made by Germany for ''gleichberechtigung'' ("equality of status" i.e. abolishing Part V of the Treaty of Versailles, which had disarmed Germany) and the French demand for ''sécurité'' ("security" i.e. maintaining Part V).
** The [[League of Nations]] again recommends negotiations between the [[Republic of China (1912–49)|Republic of China]] and Japan.
** The [[Reconstruction Finance Corporation]] begins operations in Washington, D.C.
```

Then I use this pattern to get the line which begin with `*`: `/^\*{1}(.*)/g`.
And I also use this pattern to get every line which begin with `**`: `/^\*{2}(.*)$/gm`